# Use enumitem to change style of sublist globally

Tags: lists, enumitem

I know I can change the style of lists globally as follows:

```
\setlist[enumerate]{label=({\roman*})}
```

When I open a new list inside a list, I can change its style individually:

```
\begin{enumerate}[label=(G\arabic*)]
```

How can I change the style of a sublist globally?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to specify the level number with `\setlist`

E.g. In order to change the 2nd level, say `\setlist[enumerate,2]{...}` where `...` stands for the changes.

This works for 1,2,3,4 levels (there aren't more levels for `enumerate`).

Omitting the number means: `All levels`, which is an error, in most cases.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}


\setlist[enumerate]{label=({\roman*})}

\setlist[enumerate,2]{label=({G\arabic*})}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item Foo
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item Should be arabic numbers
    \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @tomet: You're welcome. Happy TeXing.